# Get value from input date and show in the another input date by ajax

Tags: jquery, date, input

When `<input class="boton" type="checkbox">` is changed, get value from `<input type='date' id='fechai' name='fechai' class='fechai'>` and show it on `<input type="date" id="fechai-cambio" name="fechai5">` with ajax. Can include jquery.
Ive tried multiple things but I can only get it to show on the alert.... I posted both of them below just in case because the second one is shown within a while. I need for the first date to show in all the boxes that have been checked.

```
    $('.boton').change(function () {
        var fechai = new Date($('#fechai').val());

         $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: {fechai:fechai},
            success: function(response){
                //Show the var fechai in the #fechai-cambio
             alert(fechai); 
            }
          });


        });
```

```
<label for='superv' >Nombre de Equipo</label>
            <select name='superv' id='superv'>
            '<option></option>'";
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($superv))
                {
                    echo "<option value='$row[IDSUPERVISOR]'>$row[NOMEQUIPO]</option>";
                }           
        echo"    </select>                     
        <label for='cantp' >Cantidad de Personas</label>
            <input type='text' id='cantp' name='cantp' readonly>
        <label for='razon' >Fecha Inicio</label>
            <input type='date' id='fechai' name='fechai' class='fechai' >
        <br>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         echo ' <tr>
                <td>'.$row['NOMBRE'].' '.$row['APELLIDO_P'].'</td>
                <td class="text-center"><input class="boton" type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$row['IDLIBRETA_PERSONAL'].'"></td>
                <td><input type="date" id="fechai-cambio" name="fechai5" ></td>
                <td>'.$row['NOMBRE'].'</td>

                </tr>';
        }    
        echo "<button id='btn_form' type='button' onclick='realizaGrupo()'>Grabar</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not why you want to use AJAX. Where you can simply do like this with jquery

```
$('.boton').change(function () {
    var fechai = $('#fechai').val();
    $('#fechai-cambio').val(fechai);
});
```

Comment: great, thanks it works. But with id, I can only get the first checkbox's date not all of the checkboxes (the checkbox and the date #fechai-cambio for each checkbox)